# Nested objects using WTForms (or FormEncode)?

Tags: wtforms, formencode

What's the best practice for creating a form with nested objects/fields?

I have a Team object, with a field "name", and a team can consist of 1 to many (lets say 12) members, each of whom has a name, an e-mail, age, t-shirt size etc.
I'd like to validate all of them in one go. So that I would post all the team members as an array.. the field names would be something like 
members[0].name
members[1].name
or whatever the form validator would be able to parse.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create one Form for the Team and one Form for a Member. In the Team-form, create a FieldList of FormFields:

```
class Member(Form):
    name = StringField("Name")
    ...

class Team(Form):
    ...
    members = FieldList(FormField(Member))
```